# link_to_remote does not generate correct url in Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In Haml, I've been trying to get the following link_to_remote call to work. It's called from the `/questions/new` view.

```
#{link_to_remote image_tag('x.png'), :url => {:controller => 'questions', :action => 'remove_tag_from_cart'}}
```

I've tried the following variations.

```
#{link_to_remote image_tag('x.png'), :url => {:controller => :questions, :action => :remove_tag_from_cart}}
#{link_to_remote image_tag('x.png'), :controller => 'questions', :action => 'remove_tag_from_cart'}
#{link_to_remote image_tag('x.png'), :controller => :questions, :action => :remove_tag_from_cart}
```

In every case, I get the following link: `/questions/new#`. I'm not sure why!

I also have the following in routes.rb, thinking that was the problem...

```
map.connect ':controller/remove_tag_from_cart', :action => 'remove_tag_from_cart'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
map.connect ':controller/remove_tag_from_cart', :controller=>:controller , :action => 'remove_tag_from_cart'
```

Restart server and check.

EDITED

link_to_remote use for the ajax request. so when you hover the link you will get your url append with # but when you click on it it call the ajax request to a url provided by you. i explain it below.

```
<%= link_to_remote image_tag('x.png'), :url => {:controller => 'questions', :action => 'remove_tag_from_cart'}} %>
```

when you check generated html using it you will get

```
<a onclick="new Ajax.Request('/questions/remove_tag_from_cart', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); return false;" href="#">
   <img src="/images/x.png" alt="X"/>
 </a>
```

you can see **href="#"** in your generated html

Note:if you don't want it either you have to use link_to.

Answer (score 0):

if /questions/new# is what shown in your status bar in browser then check page source again because link_to_remote generates javascript ajax request and actual link is hidden inside onclick attribute